# Text sorting layout on “answers” is broken on mobile

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, responsive-design, mobile-safari

Just notice how the formatting is off in the middle where you can choose to sort by tab group.

[image]

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please don't forget to upvote and [accept it by clicking the green check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! I deployed a fix for it. Now "Sorted by" should display above the dropdown menu.